# Spring programmatic transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have code that has transactions demarcated programmatically.

Currently I have the isolation set to `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW`. Which works fine however I need to cater for recursive behaviour and for that I don't want a new transaction created if the method is called again from the same thread.

1) If the method is called first time, suspend current transaction and create new transaction. `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW`

2) If it is called recursively. Don't create a new transaction.

Example: What I have and it works is. What I don't want is the use of entrancy AtomicInterger. Any ideas?

```
public methoda() {

  Integer entrancy = rentrancy.incrementAndGet(); 

   if(entrancy == 1) { 
          this.transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(..PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
   }

   this.transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<E>(){
         .......
         .......
   }
   entrancy.decrementAndGet();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like PROPAGATION_REQUIRED is better suited for your purpose. From its javadoc:

*Support a current transaction; create a new one if none exists.*

Comment: no it wont because, i need a new transaction when this method is called the very first time. but if it recursive, i dont want another new transaction.

Comment: I would look refactor the code in a way transaction is created around the first call only, perhaps pull this up to another method. This will be cleaner than messing with conditional propagation mode etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that my "workaround" will be work, becouse I can't test it now.
But - If you use anotation(@Transactional) for define transaction that the transaction will be created only when method called external. Not if method call self. This is so becouse proxy.

"Note: Since this mechanism is based on proxies, only 'external' method calls coming in through the proxy will be intercepted. This means that 'self-invocation', i.e. a method within the target object calling some other method of the target object, won't lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional!"
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html